# how to use many LIKE conditions in SQL easily?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I want to use many LIKE conditions in my query. I couldn't find a practical solution. I tried CONTAINS but it doesn't work.

Instead of using this

```
where EIO.DigiAddress like '%abc@abc.com%'
or EIO.DigiAddress like '%def@def.com%'
or EIO.DigiAddress like '%ghi@ghi.com%'
```

I want to use something like this:

```
CONTAINS(EIO.DigiAddress,'%abc@abc.com%', '%def@def.com%', '%ghi@ghi.com%')
```

OR

```
EIO.DigiAddress IN ('%abc@abc.com%', '%def@def.com%', '%ghi@ghi.com%')
```

Comment: Is it a specific set of strings like that, or a common format, like an email address?

Comment: Why do you use LIKE `'%abc@abc.com%'` for e-mail address which is defined you should just use `='abc@abc.com'`

Comment: If your intention is to check for valid email addresses. Then the last % is not needed!

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need many LIKE onditions? Usually it's best to avoid them as they are pretty costly. So -- what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610796/is-there-any-way-to-combine-in-with-like-in-an-sql-statement, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130907/how-to-combine-in-operator-with-like-condition-or-best-way-to-get-comparable-re, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019745/combining-like-with-in-in-sql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408900/sql-server-combining-like-and-in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql etc.

Comment: When I look at all the answers below, I think that multiple LIKEs are still the best and cleanest solution. Sorry, but that's how you do it in SQL.

Comment: @Ben yes you are right. I will check them

Comment: @valex I can't use equal because email address column contain values like "BLA BLA BLA <abc@abc.com>"

Answer (score 5):

**Try this:**

Create a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (
    alternate VARCHAR(20)
);
```

then:

```
INSERT INTO temp
VALUES ('%abc@abc.com%'), ('%def@def.com%'), ('%ghi@ghi.com%');
```

Select:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl t JOIN temp p ON (t.col LIKE p.alternate);
```

Comment: Does creating a temp table slows down the query?

Comment: @cihata87 i guess no.....

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong in using LIKE. But if you don't like LIKE then use this (for MS SQLSERVER)

```
where PATINDEX('%abc@abc.com%', EIO.DigiAddress) >0 OR
      PATINDEX('%def@def.com%', EIO.DigiAddress) >0 OR
      PATINDEX('%ghi@ghi.com%', EIO.DigiAddress) >0
```

Note: You have to use relevant string function for PATINDEX depending on the database you use.

Comment: Better yet CHARINDEX because it is faster in his case.

Comment: PATINDEX can use wildcard characters, but CHARINDEX cannot. Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190184(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: He's only using wildcards at the ends. It looks like his intention is a "contains" style search.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
where EIO.DigiAddress regexp '[a-c|e-g|g-i]{3}@{1}[a-c|e-g|g-i]{3}.com'
```